# Username and Password in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, passwords, save

I am trying to make a Python script where users can create an account and log in. I need to save their account details (Name, DoB, etc.) so they can close the program and log in again next time.

```
#username:Password
account = {"Admin":["Pog"],"Hughes":["Hughes"], "E": ["Echo"], "C": ["Charlie"], "B": ["Bravo"], "D": ["Delta"], "A": ["Alpha"]}

#Check Credentials
name=input("Username: ")                    #Ask for name
if name in account:                         #Check name exists
    print (account[name][0])                #Error test - print expected password
    if passw==account[name][0]:             #Check for password match
        print("welcome,", name)             #Welcome message
else:
    print ("Failed Authentication")     #Wrong Password
else:
    print("Username Not Known")             #Unknown Username
```

The above code works, I can authenticate users but how do I add new users/Passwords so that they will be added to the program?

I have been experimenting with writing/reading to/from txt files but without success. Is this the right approach?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

(I have tried searching but can't find what I'm looking for. [How to create a python dictionary that will store the username and password for multiple accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044935/how-to-create-a-python-dictionary-that-will-store-the-username-and-password-for)  was close)

Comment: pls fix your code indentation. The right approach would be a database, you can start sqlite or MySql, but not textfiles.

Comment: Fixed indentation

Answer (score 0):

yep you will need to either use an external file as a constant storage or else use a database of some sort to store that data. Otherwise when you restart the script, it'll drop everything thats currently in memory (stored during the last script run)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using Pickle:

...

```
account = pickle.load(open("accounts.pkl","rb"))  #Load Accounts file
#Check Credentials
name=input("Username: ")                    #Ask for name
if name in account:                         #Check name exists
    print (account[name][0])                #Error test - print expected password
    passw=input("Password: ")               #Ask for Password
    if passw==account[name][0]:             #Check for password match
        print("welcome,", name)             #Welcome message
        print("your Favourite Artist is: ",account[name][2])
        menu(name,account)
    else:
        print ("Failed Authentication")     #Wrong Password
        users()
else:
    print("Username Not Known")             #Unknown Username
    new_user(account)
```

Where the account details are stored like this:

```
{'Name': ['Password', 'Detail_1', 'Detail_2', 'Detail_3'],'Name2': ['Password', 'Detail_12', 'Detail_22', 'Detail_32']}
```